# Laravel File Issue

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I have two files in two different folders. I can't access one through other.

```
views/layouts/header.blade.php
views/buysalerent/buy.blade.php
```

I want to add `header.blade.php` to `buy.blade.php`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using blade templating engine, you can include one view into another view like below

In buy.blade.php, just add

```
@include('layouts.header')
```

With the above line, header will be included into your buy.blade.php

Comment: According to your suggestion I  **@include('layouts.header')** this . But it does not work .

Comment: Can you please share both views code, so that I can check what is happening wrong?

Comment: Hi , I fix the problem .

Comment: Hi Russel, I am glad to hear that you fixed the problem. Can you please share your solution. So that it can be helpful to others :-)

Comment: Hi , I fix the problem .  I change code in route                      
Route::get('buysalerent/buy',['uses' => 'RentalController@buy']);      to                         Route::get('/buy', 'RentalController@buy')->name('buy');                                 and add extends('layouts.header'); to buy.blade.php